# Overwrite default XMLRPC function from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, xml-rpc

I want to overwrite the "metaWeblog.newMediaObject" xmlrpc call so the file is saved remotely.  From mw_newMediaObject in class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php, i see that there is a hook:

```
do_action('xmlrpc_call', 'metaWeblog.newMediaObject');
```

So I should be able to do something in my plugin like:

```
add_action ('xmlrpc_call', 'myWewMediaObject');
function myWewMediaObject ($method) {
    if ($method=='metaWeblog.newMediaObject') { 
      //perform some custom action
    }
}
```

However, since the do_action call is at the beginning of the mw_newMediaObject function, I am unsure how to stop the execution after my plugin function exists.

Please let me know if I am on the right track and if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that hook just lets you tie in to the beginning of executing that function, it doesn't let you override anything.

If you want to replace this function entirely, I recommend two different options:

## 1. Don't use it

Just define your own XMLRPC method (`myNamespace.newMediaObject`) and call that instead.

## 2. Replace it

You can tie in to the `xmlrpc_methods` filter the same way you would to add a new method and can replace the callback for `metaWeblog.newMediaObject`:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'myMediaHandler' );
function myMediaHandler( $methods ) {
    $methods[ 'metaWeblog.newMediaObject' ] = 'myMediaObject';

    return $methods;
}

function myMediaObject( $args ) {
    // ... custom functionality
}
```

Just be sure to maintain the same format with the $args array and to call/apply the same actions/filters in your custom method so that you don't run into any surprises.